# what is the minimal typeorm version to postgresql 11 in Node v12.22.12 (LTS)

Tags: node.js, postgresql, typeorm

What is the minimal typeorm version to postgresql 11 in Node v12.22.12 (LTS)?

Context:

- We hope to get some feature in postgresql 11.
- It's too much pain to migrate node12 to node14
- I did know that typeorm drop support for node14 for v0.3.0.
- So, we need to find the minimalm typeorm version to postgresql 11 in node12

---

- I check the typeorm changelog, it didn't mentioned this clearly, only mentioned about what kind of function it support or not.
- I guess pg is the underlying pkg using for typeorm to talk to postgresql, so I check pg (not sure if this is a good direction for digging this), also can not find guide line on what postgresql for pg verison

the minimal typeorm version to postgresql 11 in Node v12.22.12 (LTS)

Comment: You are aware that PostgreSQL version 11 is EOL since November 2023 ?

Comment: Thanks for the information. I will consider to upgrade to higher version, but the cost for related upgrade might be too hight to make it work.